# compare the 'class' of container tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

Let's say I extract some classes from some HTML:

```
p_standards = soup.find_all("p",attrs={'class':re.compile(r"Standard|P3")})

for p_standard in p_standards:
    print(p_standard)
```

And the output looks like this:

```
<p class="P3">a</p>
<p class="Standard">b</p>
<p class="P3">c</p>
<p class="Standard">d</p>
```

And let's say I only wanted to print the text inside the `P3 classes` so that the output looks like:

```
a
c
```

I thought this code below would work, but it didn't. How can I compare the `class` name of the container tag to some value?

```
p_standards = soup.find_all("p",attrs={'class':re.compile(r"Standard|P3")})

for p_standard in p_standards:
    if p_standard.get("class") == "P3":
        print(p_standard.get_text())
```

I'm aware that in my first line, I could have simply done `r"P3"` instead of `r"Standard|P3"`, but this is only a small fraction of the actual code (not the full story), and I need to leave that first line as it is.

Note: doing something like `.find("p", class_ = "P3")` only works for descendants, not for the container tag.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after playing around with the code, it turns out that

```
p_standard.get("class")[0] == "P3"
```

works. (I was missing the `[0]`)

So this code works:

```
p_standards = soup.find_all("p",attrs={'class':re.compile(r"Standard|P3")})

for p_standard in p_standards:
    if p_standard.get("class")[0] == "P3":
        print(p_standard.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is more efficient. Use select and CSS Or syntax to gather list based on either class.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p class="P3">a</p> 
  <p class="Standard">b</p> 
  <p class="P3">c</p> 
  <p class="Standard">d</p>
 </body>
</html>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
p_standards = soup.select('.Standard,.P3')

for p_standard in p_standards:
    if 'P3' in p_standard['class']:
        print(item.text)
```